# my phone can't login to Django admin panel.(but my pc can ???)

Tags: python, django, web

i got a problem i deploy my django app with azure and azure PostgreSQL.i can login admin perfectly fine with pc but when i give link to my friend for login to admin and this happened

i want to let my friend login to admin for editing database.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: According to this question, clearing cache on the mobile device can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29612132/django-csrf-verification-failing-only-from-mobile

Comment: @NickODell Thank you it works and thank you for your advice i will delete the images